# What happens to assets created by a user when that user is deleted in Tridion?

Tags: content-manager, security

What happens to the schemas, components, templates and pages, when the user who created them is deleted?

What care should be taken while deleting a user in CMS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When a user is deleted from the CM it is actually marked as deleted, but still known in the system. The schemas, components, templates and pages will remain untouched and the deleted user is still visible in the history of the item.

For workflow it could be a bit different. I don't know what happens to a workflow activity if the assigned user is deleted.

Users can be recreated after deletion, creating a user with the same username as the deleted user will result in a new user with a new TCMuri.

Comment: If you foresee that you'll want to reinstate the same user later, then instead of deleting, you can disable the user.

Comment: True, but a disabled user will count for the CM license. There can be a scenario where you want to clean up (delete) users which are not active, but you cannot be sure if they will be reinstated later.

For example, you have a few consultants which have their own account in the active directory. They are added as users in Tridion CM and after the project is done they are disabled. After a while you might want to delete those users if the CM is close to the license limit. You never know if and when the consultants will return on the project so you might recreate the user later in time.

Comment: I thought the license limit was on active users.

Comment: I thought so too, but got confirmed & tested (Tridion 2011 SP1) it's on all users, even the inactivated ones.

Answer (score 7):

When you delete a user in Tridion, the user information is kept but the account is flagged as deleted, so all the history around items which they created/modified is kept and still visible